# Cannot read property 'rotationOffset' of undefined

Tags: json, react-360

I am using react-vr and trying to use the json object to render image, but I'm getting an error that the browser `cannot read property 'rotationOffset' of undefined`. Below is my code for reference.

```
     static defaultProps = {
            portal: 'webTour.json',
          } //assigning the json to a variable.

        componentDidMount() {
        fetch(asset(this.props.portal).uri)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseData => {
          this.init(responseData);
        })
        .done
        ();
      }

    init(tourConfig) {
        // Initialize the tour based on data file.
        this.setState({
          data: tourConfig,
          locationId: null,
          nextLocationId: tourConfig.firstPhotoId,
          rotation: tourConfig.firstPhotoRotation + (tourConfig.photos[tourConfig.firstPhotoId].rotationOffset || 0),
        });
      }

render() {
//some code

const locationId = this.state.locationId;
    const photoData = (locationId && this.state.date.photos[locationId]) || null;
    const rotation = this.state.data.firstPhotoRotation + ((photoData && photoData.rotationOffset) || 0);
    const isLoading = this.state.nextLocationId !== this.state.locationId;

return (
<Pano source = {asset(this.state.data.photos[this.state.nextLocationID].uri)} />

}
```

And below is my json file for reference.

```
{
  "nave_icon": "gateway.png",
  "firstPhotoID" : "112001",
  "firstPhotoRotation" : 90,
  "photos":{
    "112001":{
      "rotationOffset": 0,
      "uri": "CustomPano_2.jpg",
}
}
}
```

What I'm trying to do is that change the background image with the objects inside the Pano. Am I missing any essential syntax? I've spent hours to figure out the problem is not working. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: I tested the below example and it is running fine. I was wondering what I did wrong. I check the url and didn't found my answer. https://github.com/facebook/react-360/tree/master/Examples/TourSample